# python coinbase_api placing order returns "{'message': 'Invalid expire_time '}"

Tags: python, coinbase-api

i am trying to place an order with the coinbase pro api, but it fails because of the invalid expire_time.

i tried to pass the "cancel_after" parameter as timestamp, date string in iso format and seconds but still no success.
i dont really understand what is meant by

```
cancel_after    [optional]* min, hour, day
```

my params are as follows:

```
params = {
    "type":"limit", 
    "side":"buy", 
    "product_id":  "BTC-EUR", 
    "price": "1000.0", 
    "size": "0.01",
    "stop_price": "1100.0",
    "stop": "entry",
    "time_in_force": "GTT",
    "cancel_after": ? 
}
```

has some faced the same problem ?

[API-Reference for placing an order](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#place-a-new-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cancel_after    [optional]* min, hour, day
```

min,hour or day muste passed as string.

there is no real datetime value you can only set:

"min" => 1 Minute

"hour" => 1 Hour

"day" => 1 Day